# Redirect arecord output and send it with netcat

Tags: command-line, audio, redirection, alsa, netcat

I am trying to redirect sound from a microphone from one computer to another in my local network. I did following to achieve that

In one terminal:

```
arecord -t raw -c 2 -f S16_LE -r 48000 | nc -u #IP_ADDRESS# 8080
```

In another terminal:

```
nc -u -l -p 8080 | aplay -t raw -c 2 -f S16_LE -r 48000
```

However, this attempt did not result as I expected. How can I achieve redirecting sound from a microphone from one computer to another using the command-line tools a typical Linux distro has?

Answer (score 0):

From the examples coming with netcat, I gather the server needs to use the -p option, as in

```
nc -u -l -p 8080
```

Are you sure you need UDP?  You should have better quality without the "-u".

Suppose the two computers have IP addresses 192.168.1.9 (server) and 192.168.1.8 (client), then the commands would be, on the server:

```
nc -u -l -p 8080 | aplay -t raw -c 2 -f S16_LE -r 48000
```

and on the client:

```
arecord -t raw -c 2 -f S16_LE -r 48000 | nc -u 192.168.1.9 8080
```

Comment: I want it to be fast, that’s why I opted for udp.

Comment: Does it work now?

Comment: It did not work.

Comment: You need to start the server first.

Comment: I did, it doesn't work. Did you try doing it yourself?

Comment: Yes, the only problem is the lag.  Does it work when you pipe arecord directly to aplay?

Comment: I removed `-u` flag and it worked. I don't understand why it doesn't work with `-u` flag enabled. And yes to your question.

Comment: I had lots of trouble when I tested at first with UDP, while TCP worked a treat. But I just ran the test with UDP again, no sweat.  BTW, the lag has nothing to do with netcat, piping arecord to aplay directly gives me the same lag.

Comment: You don't have anything else running UDP on port 8080, do you?

Comment: No, I also tried running it on port 10000 and it didn't work. I got this error: `write(net): Connection refused`

Comment: What gave you that error, the listener?  I have no problem with port 10000. Does "/sbin/ifconfig" show you the loopback connector with address 127.0.0.1 ?

Comment: `arecord -t raw -c 2 -f S16_LE -r 48000 | nc -u 127.0.0.1 10000` is givin the error. The listener side has no problem.

Comment: That's why I asked if you have a loopback connector.

Comment: If I didn't have a loopback connector, then TCP connection wouldn't work either, would it?

Comment: You may have a point there :-(  Sorry.

Comment: I forgot that in your original question, you talk about two different computers, which means two different IP addresses, and certainly not the loopback.  I'll update my answer.